# How to make a TFont property show as default in the Object Inspector?

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, delphi-xe

**Overview**

When writing components I like to give my published properties a default value, by doing this the Object Inspector displays any newly changed properties in Bold which of course is very useful to anyone using the component as they can easily identify between default and modified values.

**Example**

Here is an example of a component containing two Color and two Font properties:

I am making the published properties `default` inside the class structure:

```
type
  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FColor: TColor;
    FColorTo: TColor;
    FFont: TFont;
    FFontHot: TFont;
    procedure SetColor(const Value: TColor);
    procedure SetColorTo(const Value: TColor);
    procedure SetFont(const Value: TFont);
    procedure SetFontHot(const Value: TFont);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Color: TColor read FColor write SetColor default clGreen;
    property ColorTo: TColor read FColorTo write SetColorTo default clBlue;
    property Font: TFont read FFont write SetFont; //< set default?
    property FontHot: TFont read FFontHot write SetFontHot; //< set default?
  end;
```

and the constructor:

```
constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  FColor := clGreen;
  FColorTo := clBlue;

  FFont := TFont.Create;
  FFont.Color := clRed;
  FFont.Name := 'Segoe UI';
  FFont.Size := 10;
  FFont.Style := [];

  FFontHot:= TFont.Create;
  FFontHot.Color := clNavy;
  FFontHot.Name := 'Verdana';
  FFontHot.Size := 8;
  FFontHot.Style := [fsItalic];
end;

destructor TMyComponent.Destroy;
begin
  FFont.Free;
  FFontHot.Free;

  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

**Problem**

The problem I have is how to make a published Font property be "marked" as default?

When I add the component to the Form both the TFont properties in the Object Inspector are in Bold (non-default). If I click the ellipse next to each published font I can see the values I set from the constructor show up - but again they are in Bold. Oddly enough though, the Size value for each font is never shown in Bold (ie appears unchanged).

Standard published properties can be made `default` very easily, but how can you do this with classes like TFont that has sub-properties?

I cannot see a way of setting the default values from the class structure, only in the constructor. Even if I could define the default values from the class structure (which seems impossible) I doubt it would work because the font has not been created yet. For example (which obviously does not work):

```
published
  property FontHot: TFont read FFontHot write SetFontHot default FFontHot.Color := clRed; //< set default?
```

So, how can I make a published TFont property show as default and unchanged when adding the new component to the Object Inspector?

I guess the same would apply to other classes similar to TFont which as sub-properties.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For object properties, the default [storage specifier](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Properties#Storage_Specifiers) is **`stored`**. After stored comes `False` (never save to DFM), `True` (save always), or a parameterless function returning either. You need the last:

```
private
  function IsFontStored: Boolean;
published
  property Font: TFont read FFont write SetFont stored IsFontStored;
```

Within the `IsFontStored` function, you can decide whether the currently set font is the *default font*. If so, return `False`.

Comment: brilliant, I would never of know about this magic word. I swear the Delphi help never assists me in finding what I need.

Comment: No need for Help; in these cases, I'd dive into the VCL code to explore how it's done there.

Comment: True I suppose, but then usually I have no idea what I am looking for or where to begin - especially when learning new things such as storage specifiers, I would not of even been aware of it until you answered the question :)

Comment: I understand completely, and indeed: the VCL code does not explain how it works nor what's its name. But what I tried to tell is that with common programmer's curiosity, a ctrl-click on a random Font property will eventually lead you to its declaration. Then, once having found the stored directive, you have your keyword to search on. Even more curiosity will result in a ctrl-click on the identifier after the stored directive, and a whole new world will unfold in front of you.... ;-)

Comment: Good point, though Ctrl+click does not always want to work. I should try and look more into the underlying Delphi code even if I do get lost in there, it is no different then trying to use the help files which are not always clear to me. Needless to say nearly every day of using Delphi I still learn new things whether by an answer like yours or from discovering it.